# How find this orthogonal tetrahedron $V_{A-BCD}$

Tags: geometry

let $ABCD$ be an orthogonal tetrahedron.and the altitudes intersect $H$,and 
$$HA=a,HB=b,HC=c,HD=d$$

Find the $V_{A-BCD}$

[image]

before to  solve this an orthogonal tetrahedron，I think we must first solve this problem

$\Delta ABC$,and  the altitudes intersect $H$,
$$HA=a,HB=b,HC=c$$

then Find this $S_{ABC}=$

[image]

[image]

let $R$ is circumradius of $ABC$,and we use this know
$$AH^2+BC^2=4R^2$$
$$BH^2+AC^2=4R^2$$
$$CH^2+AB^2=4R^2$$

Comment: Do you know whether this results in a "nice" formula?

Comment: @Blue,Hello,what is nice formula? Thank you

Comment: An *orthogonal* tetrahedron is one that has an orthogonal corner: that is, a corner that is a corner of a cube. Which vertex ($A$, $B$, $C$, or $D$) is at the orthogonal corner?

Comment: @JohnBentin: I believe the definition intended here asserts only that opposite edges determine orthogonal vectors; I call such tetrahedra "perfect" in my own work. (The right-corner tetrahedra you mention comprise a subfamily.) If indeed the intention is to consider right-corner tetrahedra, the problem gets simpler. For "perfect" tetrahedra, things are quite complicated. An explicit formula for $V$ in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ is unlikely; the best we can hope for, I think, is an implicit formula in the form of a polynomial in $V$ with coefficients that are polynomials in $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$.

Comment: @Blue: Thank you for your interpretation. I guess that $V$ means the volume of the tetrahedron. Is your $V$ the same as the OP's baffling $V_{A-BCD}$? I also don't understand why $H$ appears to be in the plane of $ABC$ in the (repeated) lower diagram and why the point $C'$ and the line segment $AH$ are distinguished. Also, I am guessing here that the OP's $S_{ABC}$ means the area of triangle $ABC$.

Comment: @JohnBentin: I think the lower diagrams relate to solving an analogous problem for triangles. I certainly take $V_{A-BCD}$ (what I call $V$) to indicate the volume of the tetrahedron (although the hyphenation is a little odd), and $S_{ABC}$ to indicate the area of the $\triangle ABC$.

Answer (score 2):

I deal with orthogonal tetrahedra a great deal, so I'll slightly-alter the notation to fit my habit.

---

Let $SABC$ be an orthogonal tetrahedron. Define $a := |SA|$ and $d := |BC|$. Also, define $p := |OP|$, with $O$ on $\overleftrightarrow{SA}$ and $P$ on $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$, such that segment $OP$ is perpendicular to both lines. (That is, $p$ is the minimum distance between the two lines. We call $OP$ an "edge-altitude" of the tetrahedron; there are, of course, two others.) The reader can verify that the tetrahedron's volume, $V$, satisfies
$$V = \frac{1}{6} a d p \qquad (\star)$$

Coordinatize the figure by placing $O$ at the origin and $P$ at $(p,0,0)$. We can write
$$S = (0,-a_1,0) \qquad A=(0,a_2,0) \qquad B=(p,0,-d_1) \qquad C=(p,0,d_2)$$
with $|a_1 + a_2| = a$ and $|d_1 + d_2| = d$. Note that $\vec{SA}\perp\vec{BC}$; for full orthogonality, we also need $\vec{SB}\perp\vec{CA}$ and $\vec{SC}\perp\vec{AB}$, so we force the dot products to vanish:
$$0 = \vec{SB}\cdot\vec{CA} = \vec{SC}\cdot\vec{AB} = a_1 a_2 + d_1 d_2 - p^2 \qquad \text{so that} \qquad p^2 = a_1 a_2 + d_1 d_2$$ 
Our tetrahedron is now completely determined by $a_1$, $a_2$, $d_1$, $d_2$.

If $H$ is the intersection of the (standard, face) altitudes, one can show that
$$H = \left( \frac{a_1 a_2}{p}, 0, 0\right)$$
(That $H$ lies on the $x$-axis says exactly that it's on edge-altitude $OP$; by symmetry, it also lies on the other edge-altitudes. That is, *all* of *both types* of altitudes pass through $H$!) We compute the following lengths
$$
\begin{align}
\sigma^2 := |HS|^2 = \frac{a_1^2}{p^2} ( p^2 + a_2^2 ) &\qquad
\alpha^2 := |HA|^2 = \frac{a_2^2}{p^2} ( p^2 + a_1^2 ) \\[6pt]
\beta^2 := |HB|^2 = \frac{d_1^2}{p^2} ( p^2 + d_2^2 ) &\qquad
\gamma^2 := |HC|^2 = \frac{d_2^2}{p^2} ( p^2 + d_1^2 )
\end{align}
$$
The above constitute a non-linear system of four equations in four parameters: $a_1$, $a_2$, $d_1$, $d_2$. (Recall that $p^2 = a_1 a_2 + d_1 d_2$.) In theory, we can solve for these parameters in terms of $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\sigma$, then substitute into the volume formula $(\star)$ and declare victory. Easier said than done. Eliminating $a_2$, $d_1$, $d_2$ from the system leaves (barring errors and/or typos) this quartic formula for $a_1^2$:

$$\begin{align}
0 &= 3 a_1^8 \; \left( \alpha^2 - 2 \beta \gamma + \sigma^2 \right) \left( \alpha^2 + 2 \beta \gamma + \sigma^2 \right) \\
%%
&+ 2 a_1^6 \; \left( 2 \alpha^6 - \alpha^4 \beta^2 - \alpha^4 \gamma^2 - 5 \alpha^2 \beta^2 \gamma^2 - 2 \beta^4 \gamma^2 - 
   2 \beta^2 \gamma^4 + 3 \alpha^4 \sigma^2 - 2 \alpha^2 \beta^2 \sigma^2 \right. \\
&\qquad\qquad \left. - 2 \alpha^2 \gamma^2 \sigma^2 + 
   19 \beta^2 \gamma^2 \sigma^2 - 3 \alpha^2 \sigma^4 - \beta^2 \sigma^4 - \gamma^2 \sigma^4 - 4 \sigma^6 \right) \\
&+ a_1^4 \; \left( -\alpha^4 \beta^4 - 2 \alpha^4 \beta^2 \gamma^2 - 2 \alpha^2 \beta^4 \gamma^2 - \alpha^4 \gamma^4 - 
 2 \alpha^2 \beta^2 \gamma^4 - \beta^4 \gamma^4 + 2 \alpha^4 \beta^2 \sigma^2 \right. \\
&\qquad\qquad \left. - 2 \alpha^2 \beta^4 \sigma^2 + 
 2 \alpha^4 \gamma^2 \sigma^2 + 16 \alpha^2 \beta^2 \gamma^2 \sigma^2 + 10 \beta^4 \gamma^2 \sigma^2 - 
 2 \alpha^2 \gamma^4 \sigma^2 \right. \\
&\qquad\qquad \left. + 10 \beta^2 \gamma^4 \sigma^2  - 9 \alpha^4 \sigma^4 + 
 8 \alpha^2 \beta^2 \sigma^4 - \beta^4 \sigma^4 + 8 \alpha^2 \gamma^2 \sigma^4 \right. \\
&\qquad\qquad \left. - 44 \beta^2 \gamma^2 \sigma^4 -
  \gamma^4 \sigma^4 - 6 \alpha^2 \sigma^6 + 6 \beta^2 \sigma^6 + 6 \gamma^2 \sigma^6 + 6 \sigma^8 \right) \\
%%
&+ 2 a_1^2 \; \sigma^2 \; \left( \alpha^2 \beta^4 \gamma^2 + \alpha^2 \beta^2 \gamma^4 + \beta^4 \gamma^4 + \alpha^2 \beta^4 \sigma^2 - 3 \alpha^2 \beta^2 \gamma^2 \sigma^2 - 4 \beta^4 \gamma^2 \sigma^2 \right. \\
&\qquad\qquad \left. + \alpha^2 \gamma^4 \sigma^2 - 4 \beta^2 \gamma^4 \sigma^2 - 2 \alpha^2 \beta^2 \sigma^4 + \beta^4 \sigma^4 - 2 \alpha^2 \gamma^2 \sigma^4 \right. \\
&\qquad\qquad \left. + 11 \beta^2 \gamma^2 \sigma^4 + \gamma^4 \sigma^4 + 3 \alpha^2 \sigma^6 - 
   3 \beta^2 \sigma^6 - 3 \gamma^2 \sigma^6 \right) \\
%%
&- \sigma^4 \; \left( \sigma^2 - \beta^2 \right)^2 \left( \sigma^2 - \gamma^2 \right)^2
\end{align}$$
We get similar quartics in $a_2^2$, $d_1^2$, and $d_2^2$. In theory, using $(\star)$, we can eliminate $a_1$, $a_2$, $d_1$, $d_2$ from consideration to get a polynomial relating $V$ and $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\delta$ directly (if implicitly). I suspect the result reduces to a quartic in some power of $V$; that seems to be how these things go. Even so, my copy of *Mathematica* has been churning away for a while without resolution ...

I've done similar tetrahedral re-parameterizations only to reach an implicit (and elaborate) polynomial relation. For instance, it's true that an orthogonal tetrahedron is determined (up to isometry) by its face areas, so we must be able to relate volume to these areas in a kind of dimensionally-enhanced Heron's formula; indeed we can, but the formula turns out to be a quartic polynomial in $V^3$ whose coefficients are polynomials in the face areas. (See the research note linked in my Bloog post, ["Heron-like Results for Tetrahedral Volume"](http://daylateanddollarshort.com/bloog/heron-like-results-for-tetrahedral-volume/).) This kind of "quartic entanglement" appears to be a fact of tetrahedral life.